# Redirection on root page not working with variations on SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, variations

I have variations enabled with 2 languages (en/fr). En is the source. I have 2 environments too, prod and test. On prod, if I visit the top most site, it actually redirects me to either /en or /fr based on my browser language settings.

However on the test environment, if I visit the top root page, there is no redirection, it just visits the default page on that site. How can I get it to redirect to the variation site like in prod?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I just needed to edit the welcome page setting in site settings to point to `/pages/VariationRoot.aspx`.